# broken port on samsung galaxy 3 and tablet wont charge

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

my charger port is broken on my Samsung tablet galaxy 3 is there another way to charge without using the port

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 has no auxiliary charging ports or removable parts - you'll need to get the port fixed or replace the tablet.

However, if you meant the Samsung Galaxy S3 (as this is what you tagged the post with) - you can purchase a [battery charging kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KEPGHSK) to charge the battery separate from the the faulty phone.